# How to remove the user if the activation link is not clicked before given time?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to implement email verification based authentication system in my django app. What exactly I want is, the email link has to expire after sometime. Even though user clicks on it, the link should not work and the user should be deleted from the database. How to do that?

forms.py:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password',]

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        print('email cleaned data: ' + self.cleaned_data['email'])
        try:
            User.objects.get(email=email)
            raise forms.ValidationError('Email already exists.')
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return email
```

views.py :

```
def register(request):
    form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.is_active = False
        # username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        # password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        # user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
    #     user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    #     if user is not None:
    #         if user.is_active:
    #             login(request, user)
    #             return render(request, 'set_goals/index.html')
    # context = {
    #     "form": form,
    # }
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        mail_subject = 'Activate your blog account.'
        message = render_to_string('registration/acc_active_email.html', {
            'user': user,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
            'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        })
        to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email = EmailMessage(
            mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
        # email.send()
        user.email_user(mail_subject,message)
        return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')
    context = {
         "form": form,
        }
    return render(request, 'set_goals/register.html', context)
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        # return redirect('home')
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

How to make the link expire? or How to delete the user from the database though he clicks the link after the given time? Please help!